# mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am getting this error, I tried all forums on this site and still doesnt understand.

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/canwechi/public_html/submit.php on line 25
0

Below is my code:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);

require "functions.php";
include "includes/vars.inc.php";

if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST['inputField']=stripslashes($_POST['inputField']);

$_POST['inputField'] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['inputField']),$link);

if(mb_strlen($_POST['inputField']) < 1 || mb_strlen($_POST['inputField'])>140)
    die("0");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO statusupdate SET tweet='".$_POST['inputField']."',dt=NOW()");

if(mysql_affected_rows($link)!=1)
    die("0");

echo formatTweet($_POST['inputField'],time());
?>
```

Comment: make sure you have valid mysql connection before using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Where is `$link` supposedly set to a value?

Comment: Also note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and are being removed from PHP distributions.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires a valid MySql connection to work, the second parameter is the resource that identifies the link that was previously made by using `mysql_connect`

A good example can be found in the [official docs](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Also note that as others mentioned in the comments to your question - the use of `mysql` extension is not recommended and it is deprecated since PHP 5.5

use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions which are more secure instead